# best way to handle ribbon menu items changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am writing code that will basically behaves like a file explorer in a browser. The tasks that are available for the displayed object items are potentially different depending on the object. So for instance, maybe I can perform Task A on a folder and Task B a file. There can be many tasks associated to the object. My thought was to hide the tasks that do not apply in the ribbon/menu bar (whatever container I use) when that type of object is selected.

Currently I'm using knockoutjs. I was going to bind to the type of the object and use conditionals to make it invisible if needed.

I am new to client side javascript and wanted to see if this is a good approach. Is it?

Comment: This question was put on hold for primarily opinion based, but, in the help center: "answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than on facts, references, or specific expertise". I think that my answer is a fact and show expertise. However, this is only my opinion, and, if you think it shpuld be closed, go on with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easies way is to use different templates for each kind of object. When you bind a template you can specify the name of the template, which would be related to the object type.

This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbustos/eusgruw6/) is a working sample of the idea. There are two different templates, named `person` and `animal` which show different properties of the object. You can apply this idea to expose different functionalities, by using different `click` bindings in each template.

I've copied it over to the following snippet:

```js
var john = { 
        name:'John', 
        age: 21 
 };
ko.applyBindings(john, shorthand);

var krispin = {
    name: 'Krispin',
    breed: 'Akita Inu'
};

var vmExplicit = {
    john: john,
    krispin: krispin
};
ko.applyBindings(vmExplicit, explicit);

var vmExplicit2 = { 
    items: [ 
        { name: 'person', data: john},
     { name: 'animal', data: krispin}],
};
ko.applyBindings(vmExplicit2, explicit2);
```

```css
.a {
    border: solid 1px silver;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

h5 {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h5>Shorthand</h5>
<div id="shorthand">
  <div data-bind="template: 'person'" class="a"></div>
</div>

<h5>Explicit</h5>
<div id="explicit">
    <div data-bind="template: {name: 'person', data: john}" class="a"></div>
    <div data-bind="template: {name: 'animal', data: krispin}" class="a"></div>
</div>

<h5>Explicit 2</h5>
<div id="explicit2">
    <div data-bind="foreach: items">
        <div data-bind="template: $data" class="a"></div>
    </div>
</div>
   

<script type="text/HTML" id="person">
    <h5>Person template</h5>
    Name: <span data-bind="text:name"></span><br/>
    Identity number: <span data-bind="text:age"></span>
</script>

<script type="text/HTML" id="animal">
    <h5>Animal template</h5>
    Name: <span data-bind="text:name"></span><br/>
    Breed: <span data-bind="text:breed"></span>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little example of how it could be done in Knockout. You have a selection of three tools, each enables certain buttons. When no tool is selected, the buttons are not displayed. When a tool is selected, the buttons display, but only the ones that should be enabled for that tool are enabled.

I've added another method for when the rules are a bit more complicated. In that case, you'll want to have a `computed` to figure whether the tool should be enabled. The tool must have `canDoA` *and* the `waiver` checkbox must be checked for the Danger button to be armed.

```js
function tool(name, canDoA, canDoB) {
  return {
    name: name,
    canDoA: canDoA,
    canDoB: canDoB,
    click: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  };
}

vm = {
  tools: [
    tool('First', true, false),
    tool('Second', false, true),
    tool('Third', true, true)
  ],
  selectedTool: ko.observable(),
  waiver: ko.observable(),
  boom: function() {
    console.log("BOOM!");
  }
};
vm.bigButtonEnabled = ko.computed(function() {
  return vm.selectedTool() && vm.selectedTool().canDoA && vm.waiver();
});
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```css
.big-button {
  font-size: 200%;
  color: white;
}
.big-button:enabled {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
Tool:
<select data-bind="options:tools, optionsText: 'name', optionsCaption: '--Select--', value:selectedTool"></select>

<!-- ko with:selectedTool -->
<button data-bind="enable:canDoA, click: click.bind($data, 'A')">A</button>
<button data-bind="enable:canDoB, click: click.bind($data, 'B')">B</button>
<!-- /ko -->
<div>
  Waiver signed:
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:waiver" />
  <br />
  <button data-bind="enable:bigButtonEnabled, click: boom" class="big-button">Danger</button>
</div>
```